# Where can I find a NuGet package for upgrading to System.Web.Http v5.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, asp.net-web-api2

Just upgraded an ASP.NET MVC4 project to use Unity.WebApi version 5.0.0.0 and it requires System.Web.Http v 5.0.0.0 as per the following error:

```
Assembly 'Unity.WebApi, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=43da31bc42a85347' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I am currently referencing System.Web.Http v4.0 but have the following NuGet packages upgraded to their respective latest versions:

- ANTLRv3
- Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC
- Microsoft ASP.NET Razor
- Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers Core Libraries
- Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 Client
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 Core
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 Web Host
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Page
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- WebGrease

  via NuGet.  I have not listed relevant JavaScript libraries such as Micrososft.jQuery.Unobtrusive Validation, etc.

What is the NuGet package to upgrade System.Web.Http or do I have to do this manually?

Comment: If you select "Include Prerelease" instead of "Stable" in the NuGet Package Manager, you'll see System.Web.Http. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: am I supposed to be searching for System.Web.Http after selecting "Include Prerelease"? Or where should I be looking?

Comment: Disregard my above comment! That package is outdated. You should try to follow Stjin's suggestion below. Strangely enough, when I install Unity.WebApi in *my* MVC 4 project, it updates the System.Web.Http reference to v5.0 automatically, so I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. If all else fails, you could try uninstalling the Unity package and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You need the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/) package.

You can see it in the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I have Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 Core (id= Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core ) upgraded to v5.0.0.0 as listed above.  Looks like I need to remove and re-add them?

Comment: Had to also clean, delete bin_deployableAssemblies and rebuild.

Comment: Having almost the exact same project. Where is the bin_deployable Assemblies folder that everyone keeps talking about?

Comment: @nzondlo I believe that folder is generated when Publishing an application. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: @nzondlo `bin_deployableAssemblies` is just a regular folder, but it gets special treatment when it exists in your project's directory. Any .dll file in that folder is copied to the bin directory when you publish your web application. It was used to deploy the System.Web.Mvc dll (and others) with your web app before NuGet became mainstream.

Answer (score 10):

I have several projects in a solution.  For some of the projects, I previously added the references manually.  When I used NuGet to update the WebAPI package, those references were not updated automatically.

I found out that I can either manually update those reference so they point to the v5 DLL inside the Packages folder of my solution or do the following.

1. Go to the "Manage NuGet Packages"
2. Select the Installed Package "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1"
3. Click Manage and check the projects that I manually added before.

Comment: Uninstalling the package and then immediatley reinstalling it fix it for me. Happened when bringing the project up on a different development machine. Automatic package restore got the wrong version somehow.

Comment: Main problem is updating Web.Api for main project but referenced projects are still using older version of it. It should be update together via right clicking the Solution name and Manage Nuget Packages menu as @Tony mentioned. cheers!

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core