# visual studio unit test project missing assemblies (while using Moq)

Tags: .net, api, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

So I have a solution contains two project: Example.Api and Example.Api.Test.

Example.API project is my Web API 2 project that talks to Database.

Example.API.Test project is there to unit test against Example.API.

I'm using moq to mock the context and controllers and more.

One problem is that my Example.API.Test project misses a lot assemblies used by Example.API project.

Test project has reference to the Example.API project but all the system assemblies are missing.

for example, The type 'System.Web.Http.ApiController' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Http ...

I could add individual reference to Example.API.Test project but it seems not the right way.

Any tips available?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course you must install *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core* in your test project as well. Use nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/

Comment: So basically I need to separately install missing assemblies right? seems like wasting space :)

Comment: Yes easily via Nuget `Install-Package`

Comment: it turned out webapicore is installed. What's missing is 'System.Web.Http'. When I manually added the reference now it gives  error saying:                                                                                  Assembly 'Example.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Comment: and nuget doesn't help me with update this specific assembly. :(

Comment: You don't have to add System.Web.Http manually. Installing *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core* must include that for you.

Comment: install-Package System.Web.Http -Version 5.2.2.0 fails :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62290/discussion-between-joseph-jeganathan-and-codeschool-jj).

Comment: oop look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202188/where-can-i-find-a-nuget-package-for-upgrading-to-system-web-http-v5-0-0-0

Answer (score 23):

Just Follow other's advice! Do Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core evenif nuget says it has it.

:)

Quote as Joseph told me "You can easily install the same version by managing packages (right click on the solution level)"

Thank you!

Comment: you can remove your manually added dependencies and install via nuget so visual studio will install you all the required dependencies and configurations. run following command in nuget package manager console Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core

Comment: This fixed my issue!